# Sibelius playback of triplets

Tags: sibelius

I am trying to notate a basic 3 over 4 rhythm, but the playback feature is making me think I don't know what I am doing. Notation problems aside, is the following two measures, rhythmically enharmonic? [image]

Basically, am I wrong to think that a triplet (or tuplet) can be subdivided by 16th's and 32nds?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving aside your misprint - the tuplet number in your second bar should be a 4 of course - yes they're both OK.

In my example below, A, B and C are all acceptable.  I prefer C.  Some would say the modern trend is to favour A.

Yes, you can subdivide notes in a tuplet.  And it can get even more complicated than D if you want, with tuplets inside tuplets.  Today's 'modern classical' composers regularly come up with much worse than E!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those two measures are rhythmically equivalent. Reasonable cheat, eh?

Your second measure has a huge notation problem that obscures readability, though: that tuplet bracket is supposed to say 4 (for quadruplet) instead of 3 (for triplet). I think my brain automatically corrected it at first glance, so I didn't initially notice this egregious error until it was almost too late. This error is so bad that I'm surprised that the tuplet plays back properly. Did you purposefully change the 4 to a 3?

Comment: Yeah, I know it was supposed to be a “4,” just goofed. You all knew what I was saying. Thanks for all the confirmations guys!

Comment: In the last year I have started taking my composing seriously, and inevitably you happen upon an idea that you cannot play, let alone notate.

Comment: @JasonHuff - Musescore notates the 4 properly by default, and I suspect so does Sibelius (and Finale). I really don't know how there's a 3 instead in your image.